# Titanium appcelerator Android Drill down

Tags: android, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile, drilldown

I am having difficulties to find a way to drill down my tableview created for Android. I have 2 or 3 levels of data and I see its not working the same way as for iOS so my question is how the hell to implement drill down for Android?

I heard it should be done with views or something similar. Maybe someone could show an example of passing from one row to another list of data changing window or content of current window?^

thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what issue you're seeing, and perhaps include some code?